# Angular Ionic back button only working after I slide the pointer on It

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

So basically, I have this simple code that should be working fine but for some reason I'm getting a rare bug.

I have a page called "home" and a sidemenu which I use to navigate to the page "mysports". When It first loads the page "mysports", it displays the `ion-back-button`, but whenever I try to click it, it doesn't work. When I click the `ion-back-button` and slide it to the left, the HTML refreshes and the `ion-back-button` works perfectly fine.

On my html I have this code:

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
     <ion-buttons>
        <ion-back-button text="Back"></ion-back-button>
        <ion-label>
          <ion-title class="ion-text-center">spoRts</ion-title>
        </ion-label>
     </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
    
<ion-content>
    
</ion-content>
```

I don't have anything else only this. Didn't even touch the `mysports.page.ts` file.

Comment: Looks like my sidemenu I had from the previous page was displaying invisible because I used this.router.navigateByUrl(). Fixed it using menuController and closing it manually after navigating to the next page

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put "defaultHref="your_route" inside the ion-back-button tag like this:

```
<ion-buttons slot="start">
    <ion-back-button defaultHref="contacts"></ion-back-button>
</ion-buttons>
```

I hope to help you, regards.

Answer (score 0):

the structure of your header is wrong. When he's not right he does rare bugs. you must change it for the following:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
            <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title>spoRts</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

additionally if you want to change the text of the backbutton you can do it globally on app.module.ts:

```
        IonicModule.forRoot({
            backButtonText: 'Back',
            backButtonIcon: 'arrow-back-outline',
        }),
```